# Error apache Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache, xampp, localhost

Buen día, estimados.

Estoy usando Ubuntu 20.04 LTS y estoy instalando el xampp, pero al ejecutar los servicios, el apache no me enciende, me aparece lo siguiente,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisé el error log y me aparece lo siguiente,

`(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80`

`(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`

`no listening sockets available, shutting down`

`AH00015: Unable to open logs`

Por favor si serían tan amables de ayudarme a solucionarlo, gracias.

Comment: Parece que ya tienes una instalación de apache en el equipo. Prueba "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop" antes de iniciar xampp

Comment: Muchas gracias nashvent, me funcionó! cada vez que necesite usar el servicio tendría que desconectarlo?

Comment: Puedes deshabilitar el servicio  de apache asi "sudo systemctl disable apache2". De esta forma no tendras que ejecutar el comando anterior cada vez que quieras usar xampp

Comment: gracias nash! muy amable!

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que ya tenía el servicio instalado, así que tuve que detener el servicio que ya se estaba ejecutando con:
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
y luego encender el xampp, gracias al usuario nashvent.